# How do you insert a LaTeX equation in PowerPoint under Windows?

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint, latex

I was wondering how may I insert latex equations into powerpoint directly without the use of Microsoft Windows to convert latex to Microsoft equations then copy and past.

I understand from this [link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-insert-a-LaTeX-equation-in-PowerPoint) that one may either use

1) LaTeXiT (Mac)

2) TeXPoint (not free- windows)

3) IguanaTeX (free - windows)

However, the installations of any of the last two add-ins are not easy and often did not work with me. May there be anyone that may describe the procedure easily?

Comment: Perhaps you can use Overleaf (http://www.overleaf.com/) to generate pictures that can be included in your PowerPoint slides.